# Am trying to load a test in myserver with JMeter. I created the script using Groovy and tried to run it on JMeter but it gave internal server error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How to overcome this, I face the issue when using ELB in AWS server. But I tried to hit the load in server directly means, it works.

Here I try with ELB, System arise the `error code 500(Internal Server error)` . How to solve this issue.

```
Thread Name: Set Workout 2-92  
Sample Start: 2018-12-11 15:05:47 IST  
Load time: 109085  
Connect Time: 551  
Latency: 109085  
Size in bytes: 238  
Sent bytes:1798981  
Headers size in bytes: 158  
Body size in bytes: 80  
Sample Count: 1  
Error Count: 1  
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text  
Response code: 500  
Response message: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Already I tried Cookie manager also .